# Check if field is empty in Views field Template

Tags: views, entities

I have about 4 fields displayed in a view.

What I am looking to achieve is when one of the fields have a check box ticked, to hide a different field in the view display. e.g

Price on application [Ticked and displayed]

Price GBP [Hidden]

Price USD [Hidden]

OR

Price on application [Un-Ticked]

Price GBP [Dispalyed]

Price USD [Dispalyed]

I am editing the views-view-field.tpl for 'Price USD' and 'Price GBP' field.
(views-view-field--clone-of-gallery--gallery--field-listing-price-usd.tpl.php)

The basics I am trying to achieve are:

```
if 'price_on_application' = '1'
"Empty"
else
Print $output
```

The if statements i have tried so far are:

```
<?php if ($row->field_listing_price_on_request == "POA"): ?>
<?php if ($field->field_listing_price_on_request == '1'): ?>
```

and several other variations of the above.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Views Conditional](https://drupal.org/project/views_conditional) module. With it, you can add a conditional field that would evaluate the value of your 'Price on application' field. You can then add the other two fields in a personalize text excluded from display and use you conditional field to display it or not depending on the condition you want.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this module out. Works like a dream. My only tip I have learnt is if you are using it with boolean field you must have set both an On and Off value for it to work.